# объеденить строчки json

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеется такой json:

```
{art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"}
{art: "2", quan: "1", sum: "1"}
{art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"}
{art: "12", quan: "1", sum: "1"}
{art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"}
{art: "12", quan: "1", sum: "1"}
{art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"}
{art: "11", quan: "1", sum: "1"}
{art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"}
```

Подскажите, как мне найти повторы по полю 'art', удалить повторы и сложить поля quan и sum.

То есть в итоге должно получиться :

```
{art: "1", quan: "4", sum: "4"}
{art: "2", quan: "1", sum: "1"}
{art: "12", quan: "2", sum: "2"}
{art: "11", quan: "1", sum: "1"}
```

Код:

```
function filterArt(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
            if (arr[i].art == arr[j].art){
                arr[i].quan = +arr[i].quan + (+arr[j].quan);
                arr[i].sum = +arr[i].sum + (+arr[j].sum);
                arr.splice(j,1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код не совершенен. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать.

Comment: И если я не ошибаюсь надо получить `{art: "1", quan: "4", sum: "4"}` или `{art: "1", quan: "5", sum: "5"}`, потому что `art` со значением один в массиве 5 раз повторяется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы ошиблись когда сделали во втором цикле `j < arr.length - i`:
Тогда в определенных случаях, ваш `i` элемент не сравнится с последними элементами массива.

```js
var arr = [
    {art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "2", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "12", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "12", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "11", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"}
];

function filterArt(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i].art == arr[j].art) {
                arr[i].quan = +arr[i].quan + (+arr[j].quan);
                arr[i].sum = +arr[i].sum + (+arr[j].sum);
                arr.splice(j, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(filterArt(arr));
```

Comment: спасибо большое, не увидел этого

Answer (score 0):

Вы в вашем алгоритме для каждого элемента массива пробегаетесь по всем другим элементам, в итоге сложность получается O(n^2). Проще Завести один объект и пробегаться по всем существующим и уже дальше смотреть - если есть элемент с таким arr (сделать его индексом), то приплюсовывать значения. Если же такого нет - то создавать, с теми значениями что у текущего объекта.

В крайнем случае, если вам нужно чтобы art был не индексом, а именно одним из свойств - можете пробежаться по получившемуся объекту и занести значения индексов в элемент.

```js
var objs = {};
$('.json').each(function(){
  var obj = JSON.parse($(this).html());
  if (objs[obj.art]){
    objs[obj.art].quan += parseInt(obj.quan);
    objs[obj.art].sum += parseInt(obj.sum);
  } else {
    objs[obj.art] = {
      quan: parseInt(obj.quan),
      sum: parseInt(obj.sum)
    }
  }
});

$('.result').html(JSON.stringify(objs));
```

```css
.json{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="json">{"art": "1", "quan": "1", "sum": "1"}</div>
<div class="json">{"art": "2", "quan": "1", "sum": "1"}</div>
<div class="json">{"art": "1", "quan": "1", "sum": "1"}</div>
<div class="json">{"art": "12", "quan": "1", "sum": "1"}</div>
<div class="json">{"art": "1", "quan": "1", "sum": "1"}</div>
<div class="json">{"art": "12", "quan": "1", "sum": "1"}</div>
<div class="json">{"art": "1", "quan": "1", "sum": "1"}</div>
<div class="json">{"art": "11", "quan": "1", "sum": "1"}</div>
<div class="json">{"art": "1", "quan": "1", "sum": "1"}</div>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

убрал второй for из примера @Razmik Galstyan

```js
var arr = [
    {art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "2", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "12", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "12", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "11", quan: "1", sum: "1"},
    {art: "1", quan: "1", sum: "1"}
];
function filterArt(arr) {
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length;) {
        var art = arr[i].art,
            j = obj[art];
        if (j !== void 0) {
            arr[j].quan = +arr[i].quan + +arr[j].quan;
            arr[j].sum = +arr[i].sum + +arr[j].sum;
            arr.splice(i, 1)
        } else obj[art] = i++
    }
    return arr
};
console.log(filterArt(arr));
```